# cordova IOS app all onclick and back button not working for latest IOS 11.3.1

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, html-framework-7, hybrid

dear ios hybrid app rock stars,

i have developed IOS app using Framework7 with Cordova 7.0.1.
It was work fine before update mobile to IOS version 11.3.1.
But not all of devices using this app get updated to latest IOS version.

Now the problem happen.
When app open at the first time it works fine in all pages. Pages swipe and onclick to back button and menu onclick works fine.

But when we lock the phone with the app remain open behind. Then unlock the phone then click of the any function not working except the swipe of screens. onclick event and backbutton not working. Even menu also not open when we click icon for menu.

Again if we close the app completely then open again it will work fine.

only when we lock the device without close of the app (remain open) then again unlock the device and use app not working correctly. That makes the all click event not working. even menu links also not able to click.

P.s. App working fine on apple 4s with the IOS 9.3.5.

Any one have resolved this type of issue.

Video reference attached here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1jPau0FmVak7ePCc8JNdzwJvSj3KuXBTm
there you can see menu, back and refresh icons clicked but its not working..

Answer (score 1):

This is due to a bug in iOS 11.3 where the touch event `timeStamp` is being reported as negative value.

There have been commits to fix this in Framework7 [v1](https://github.com/framework7io/framework7/commit/e1906b03b5273a31387f05eb2b914daf2e89f56c) and [v2](https://github.com/framework7io/framework7/commit/ac02ad1514f53ddd47a663f281104049ae59cb52) so the solution is to update the version of F7 in your app to the latest (right now that's v2.2.5 / v1.7.1).

See [this discussion](http://forum.framework7.io/t/ios-11-3-phonegap-resume-problem/2912/14) for more detail.